# ¿Cómo hago para traducir una fecha?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy formateando una tabla. Esperaba que en la columna fecha el formato fuera "viernes 2 de mayo". De alguna forma, lo logré... solo que en en inglés: "Friday 2 de may". Probé en traducirlo, pero la hoja de cálculos no toma la traducción, y en lugar de es pone "02/05/20".

```
function formatearSSheet(e) {

  let ssheet = e.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = ssheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 9);
  var range = ssheet.getDataRange();
  
  /* Formateo de fecha*/
  var lastrow = range.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2 ; i < lastrow + 1 ; i++) {
    var fecha = ssheet.getRange(i, 2);
    var fechav = fecha.getValue();
    var fechaform = Utilities.formatDate(fechav, "GMT", "EEEE MMMM d" ); // La fecha queda en inglés .
    var fechaes = LanguageApp.translate(fechaform, 'en', 'es'); // Traducción al español... aunque supongo que ahora es un string.
    fecha.setValue(fechaes);
    //Logger.log(fechaes); // La fecha en español aparece correctamente en el debug.
  }
  
  /* Formateo de hora*/
  for (var i = 2 ; i < lastrow + 1 ; i++) {
    var hora = ssheet.getRange(i, 4);
    var horav = hora.getValue();
    var horaform = Utilities.formatDate(horav, "GMT", "h:mm" );
    hora.setValue(horaform);
  }
  e.getActiveSheet().autoResizeColumns(1,9);

}
```

El bucle FOR busca el dato existente en la tabla y vuelve a cargarlo con el nuevo formato.
Estoy convencido de que debe haber una forma más sencilla de hacer lo mismo.

Creo entender que `Utilities.formatDate(...)` genera un valor del tipo DATE, pero al momento de traducirlo se convierte en STRING. Aunque eso no explica por qué las fechas quedan en formato de barras 00/00/00.

FINAL

Encontré lo que buscaba.

```
  /* Formateo de fecha*/
  var lastrow = range.getLastRow();
  var rangefecha = ssheet.getRange(2, 2, lastrow + 1);
  var dateformat = ['dddd, d" de "mmmm'];
  rangefecha.setNumberFormat(dateformat);
```

Tuve que pasar un buen rato revisando la documentación.

Comment: Puede que esa columna de tu hoja esté definida para fecha. Entonces tienes dos opciones: dejarla como tal y guardar la fecha en un formato `YYYY-MM-DD` y cuando la necesites formatearla in situ, o bien cambiar el formato de esa celda a una cadena normal. Ahí perderías todas las ventajas de tener una fecha como tal y si en un futuro necesitas hacer cálculos con fechas y demás deberás reconvertir el dato. Por eso para fechas siempre se recomienda guardarlas como tal en el origen y los formatos establecerlos dinámicamente in situ, porque el formato es algo relativo.

Comment: Sí, supongo que va a ser lo mejor @ACedano. Ya intenté con `e.setSpreadsheetLocale('es');` pero no funcionó. Tal como sospechaba, `Utilities.formatDate(...);` toma un campo DATE y lo convierte en STRING, y aparentemente, solo lo hace en inglés.
El problema es que soy terco... Supongo que si uno puede cambiar el formato de una columna desde la hoja de cálculos, debería ser posible hacer lo mismo desde un script, ¿o me equivoco?

Comment: Bueno, poder sí se podría, pasando por procedimientos algo oscuros quizá pero sin sentido. Por ejemplo, si quieres esa representación en la hoja, ¿por qué no formateas allí, en la hoja? Como ya dije, el formato es algo relativo, puede que mañana necesites representar la fecha de otro modo, entonces puedes aplicar el formato que quieras a tu fecha allí donde lo necesites. Si todos modos insistes, entonces creo que tendrás que convertir esa celda en string, o bien indicar el formato al guardar, desde el script, buscando el modo de hacerlo o aplicando formato con un método de la API que exista ¿?

Comment: Gracias nuevamente @ACedano. Recién ahora voy entendiendo las dependencias y puedo buscar lo que quiero en la documentación.
El problema de hacerlo en misma hoja es que tengo que generar ¡92 hojas!
Todo esto es para automatizar la información de una escuela grande. Casi 100 profesores, 9 carreras, 250 materias y cerca de 1000 alumnos. Y todas las semanas hay algo nuevo. Estoy tratando de centralizar y automatizar el manejo de la información.

Answer (score 0):

Si la fecha se va a mostrar en al hoja de cálculo, en lugar de usar `Utilities.formatDate` o cualquier otro "artilugio" en el código del lado del servidor usa la función de formato de celda incluido en la Hoja de Cáñciñp de Gppgñe para mostrar la fecha como lo deseas. Lo mismo para la hora.

Para dar formato a una o varias celdas

1. Selecciona la celda(s)
2. Haz clic en el menú Formato > Número y luego selecciona el el formato que corresponda en la lista o bien haz clice en Mas formatos y escoge una de las opciones. Estas te mostraran varios ejemplos de formato pero podrás también crear un formato personalizado.